# Any problems with using TCP and UDP in the same application?

Tags: java, android, tcp, udp

The point of my question is to ask if it is accepted to use both TCP and UDP to communicate between client and server.

I am making a real-time client server game with parts of the communication that need to be guaranteed (logging in, etc..), but other parts will be ok to lose packets (state updates, etc). So, I would like to use UDP for most of the data communication but I do not want to have to implement my own framework to insure that my control communication (logging in) is guaranteed.

So, would it be reasonable to initially use TCP to manage a connection, and then on a separate port send data communication pack and forth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should absolutely do it that way (use TCP and UDP to accomplish different communication tasks.) And you don't even have to use two different ports. [One will suffice](http://www.faqs.org/qa/qa-7327.html). You can listen to the two different protocols on the same port.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite reasonable and already used in mainstream. Even when browsing the Web, DNS operations are UDP-based and HTTP connections are TCP-based.

Keep in mind that you should either consider the two connection types to be completely independent or employ additional measures to properly handle any inter-dependencies. TCP connections can have timing issues at the OS and network levels and UDP connections have packet loss issues. You should take specific measures to avoid deadlocks and performance problems when the TCP part of your application stalls or a UDP packet is lost.

Comment: How could they cause problems for each other?

Comment: @gamernb: If they are independent they won't, but if for example your TCP server waits for a notification from the UDP part to send data, it could end up waiting forever if you have not taken care to handle packet loss...

Comment: Ok, I understand that. I don't plan to have them waiting on each other. The UDP part will just be something that endlessly waits for state update packets. If received, it applies it to the current client state.

Comment: thkala meant situation when for example you are waiting for message A on TCP connection and later for message B on UDP. And these messages could came even it that order over network, but because of differences in TCP and UDP stack in OS B message could be passed first to your application. You should be careful during design of your protocols message flow and handle this and similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

It is not only accepted but is widely used. As a good example, [BATS Exchange](http://batstrading.com/) is using this approach in their [market data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_data) distribution system, to implement a recovery mechanisms.